# Using Chinese Remainder Theorem to prove existence of nontrivial idempotents $\!\bmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question goes like this: use the CRT to prove that if an integer $n>1$ is not a power of a prime, then there exists an integer $x$ such that $n|(x^{2}-x)$ but $n$ does not divide $x$ nor $x-1$. I can see this working with a simple example like $n=12$, which lets $x=4,-3$. I got this by using $n|(x^{2}-x)$ to imply $x^{2}-x-nk=0$ but I cannot see to proving this with the CRT in particular. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $n$ is not a prime power. Then $n=ab$ for some **relatively prime**
numbers $a$ and $b$, both greater than $1$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists an integer $x$ such that 
$x\equiv 0\pmod{a}$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod{b}$. Thus $a$ divides $x$ and $b$ divides $x-1$. It follows that $ab$ divides $x(x-1)$.  Note that $ab$ does not divide $x$, for $b$ divides $x-1$, and therefore $b$ and $x$ are relatively prime. Similarly, one can show that $ab$ does not divide $x-1$.

Comment: Is it because gcd$(a,b)=1$ that we can construct $x$ to be a multiple of $a$ such that $a|x$ but $b|(x-1)$? Why is is that we can argue of the existence of such an $x$ where $b|(x-1)$? Which part of the CRT says this?

Comment: @Matt $\ a\mid x,\ b\mid x-1\!\iff\! x\equiv 0\pmod a,\ x\equiv 1\pmod b,\,$ i.e. $\ x\equiv (0,1)\ $ mod $\,(a,b).\,$  By CRT that has a (unique) solution mod $\,ab.\ \ $

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was how, with the information that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, we can argue that there must exist an $x$ where $x\equiv 0\pmod a$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod b$.

Comment: That is a special case of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The theorem says that if $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k$ are pairwise relatively prime, then for any $c_1,c_2,\dots, c_k$ there is a solution of the system of congruences $x\equiv c_i\pmod{m_i}$. Moreover, it says that $x$ is unique modulo $m_1m_2\cdots m_k$. Ours is  the case $k=2$, $m_1=a$, $m_2=b$, $c_1=0$, $c_2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\bmod n\,$ we seek a solution of $\ x(x-1)\equiv 0\ $ but $\,x\not\equiv 0,1.\, $ If $\,n = p^k\,$ is a prime power we get only trivial solutions: $\,p^k\mid x(x-1)\,$ $\Rightarrow\,p^k\mid x\,$ or $\,p^k\mid x-1\,$ by $\,x,\,$ $\,x-1\,$ coprime. Else $\,n\,$ is not a prime power so we can write $\,n = ab\ $ with coprime $\,a,b>1.\,$ What happens when we CRT lift the solutions $\, x\equiv 0,1\,$ mod $\,a,b\,$ to *four* solutions mod $\,n\,?$ The solutions $\,x\equiv (0,0),(1,1)\,$ mod $\,(a,b)\,$ map to $0,1\,$ mod $ab,\,$ but the solutions $\,(0,1),(1,0)\,$ mod $\,(a,b)\,$ map to values $\not\equiv 0,1\,$ mod $\,ab.$

**Remark** $\ $ Elements satisfying $\,x^2 = x\,$ (and $\,\color{#c00}{x\neq 0,1})$ are called $\rm\color{#c00}{(nontrivial)}$ *idempotents*. They are [intimately connected to coprime factorizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614256/242) (of both elements and rings). As we see above, modulo any non-prime-power composite $\,n,\,$ there are nontrivial idempotents $\,(0,1),(1,0).$

Some integer factorization algorithms work by searching for nontrivial idempotents mod $\,n,\,$ which immediately yield a factorization of $\,n\,$ ([generally one can quickly factor $\,n\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) given any polynomial which has more roots mod $\,n\,$ than its degree, so any notrivial idempotent or nontrivial square-root will split $\,n,\,$ since it yields a quadratic with $3$ roots).

Comment: I am not too strong with Abstract Algebra, but you provide an interesting comparison between it and Number Theory. I'll try my best to understand it. Also, thank you for the link!

Comment: @Matt You don't need to understand the remarks to understand the main argument. If anything there is not clear please let me know and I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: What do you mean when you refer to lifting the solutions? Also, when you use the pairwise notation? Is that just a condensed way of denoting each congruency $x$ has?

Comment: @Matt Lifting means to apply CRT to solve $\,x\equiv (c,d)\,$ mod $\,(a,b)\,$ to obtain the value of $\,x$ mod $\,ab.\,$ You can think of the pair/vector notation simply as an abbreviation, but when you study rings you will learn that these pairs have a (product) ring structure given by component-wise operations, i.e. $\,(c_1,d_1)+(c_2,d_2) = (c_1+c_2,d_1+d_2),\ $ and  $\ (c_1,d_1)(c_2,d_2) = (c_1 c_2, d_1 d_2).\,$

Comment: From this structural view, CRT says  this ring of pairs is isomorphic to $\,\Bbb Z/ab = $ integers mod $\,ab,\,$ i.e. $\,\Bbb Z/ab = \Bbb Z/a\times \Bbb Z/b\,$ is the product of the rings $\,Z/a,\, \Bbb Z/b,\,$ i.e. said ring of pairs with said component-wise  operations. For some examples of these pair (product) operations see the computations $\,(0,1)+(0,1)\,$ and $\,(1,1)+(0,1)\,$ in the final two lines of [this post.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/748982/242)