# What is a $\it{nontrivial}\,$ Square Root?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, hypothesis-testing, primality-test

I need to understand the concept behind a non trivial square root. Also how to answer these two questions and how to get to the answer?

1. Give a non-trivial square root of 30
2. Give a non-trivial square root in the integers for (mod 143)

Comment: Add some context, please! What's the ring in Q1? What are you trying to find a square root of in Q2? I might hazard a guess that non-trivial square roots emerge when a residue class has multiple square roots in the residue class ring. E.g. $\pm1$ and $\pm4$ are all square roots of $1$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_{15}$. Supposedly $\pm4$ could be called non-trivial, but this is just a guess. Chinese remainder theorem is your friend here, if this guess is correct.

Comment: I have not been given any more information just been asked to give a non trivial square root of 30 and again same thing for q2 :s

Comment: Then I would guess that you are expected to cook up the rest. For Q1 find a modulus such that 30 has four distinct modular square roots, and for Q2 find a residue class that has non-trivial square roots (hint: what's square root of $1$ modulo 143?). I have not heard of the concept of a non-trivial square root before, so it is possible that the term is private to your teacher, in which case I cannot help. As you tagged this with *primality-test*, I am somewhat optimistic about having guessed correctly. Not betting on it though.

Comment: @Jyrki There are [plenty of mentions of nontrivial square roots here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=nontrivial+square+root+mod)

Answer (score 8):

A *nontrivial* square root of $a^2$ means a root $\,b \ne \pm a,\,$ so the quadratic $\,x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)\,$ has $> 2\,$ roots $\,x = \pm a, b.\, $ Then $\,(b-a)(b+a) = 0\,$ but $\,b\pm a \ne 0,\,$ so $\,b\pm a\,$ is a [zero divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor).

[Generally we can quickly factor $\,n\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) given any polynomial which has more roots mod $\,n\,$ than its degree, so any nontrivial idempotent or nontrivial square-root will split $\,n,\,$ since it yields a quadratic with $3$ roots. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/769509/242) for a hint on how to find nontrivial square roots mod composite $\,n.\,$ There we find nontrivial idempotents, but the same idea works for square roots.

Comment: I didn't understand why a quadratic equation should have more than 2 roots. Would you mind letting me have an example (and please explain it in a simple way so I may understand; doesn't matter if you include a bit of modular arithmetic and number theory)?

Comment: @Spectre Not "should" but "could", e.g. $\,\bmod 8\!:\ x^2\equiv 1\,$ for $\,\pm x\equiv 1,3,\,$ i.e. $\,x\equiv 1,3,5,7,\,$ i.e. $\,{\rm odd}^2\equiv 1\pmod{\!8}\ \ $

Comment: so basically it's something pertaining to modular arithmetic?