# Example of a ring where two elements have the same square but neither is plus or minus the other

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

In a field $F$ and two elements $x$ and $y$ in $F$, if $x^2 = y^2$, then $x=y$ or $x=-y$. I am looking for an example of a ring $R$ such that there are two elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2 = y^2$, but neither $x=y$ nor $x=-y$.

Comment: How about quaternions?

Comment: As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) a commutative ring $R$ is a domain iff nonzero polynomials $\in R[x]\,$ have no more roots than their degree. So if $R$ has a counterexample then it has a zero divisor, say $\,ab = 0.\,$ Then $\,(a+b)^2 = (a-b)^2$ and $\,a-b\neq \pm (a+b)\,$ if $\,2a,2b\neq 0\,$ (true in  $\Bbb Z/n\,$ for odd composite $\,n).\ \ $

Comment: Also true in $\,\Bbb Z[a,b]/(ab),\,$ a *universal* example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural way to construct a counterexample would be to consider
$$R := \mathbb{Z}[x,y] / \langle y^2 - x^2 \rangle.$$
In this ring, pretty much by construction, you have $[x]^2 = [y]^2$.  So now, the point would be to see why you don't have in this ring that $[y] = [x]$ or $[y] = -[x]$.

One way to see this would be to observe that you can define a ring homomorphism $R \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $[x] \mapsto 1, [y] \mapsto -1$; therefore, you cannot have $[y] = [x]$.  Similarly, you can define a ring homomorphism $R \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $[x] \mapsto 1, [y] \mapsto 1$; therefore, you cannot have $[y] = -[x]$.  (More generally, if $S$ is another commutative ring, and you are given a pair of elements $a, b \in S$ such that $a^2 = b^2$, then there is a unique ring homorphism $R \to S$ such that $[x] \mapsto a, [y] \mapsto b$.)

Another way is: by division, you can see that every element of $R$ must be of the form $[p(x) + y q(x)]$ for some polynomials $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  If you can show that this representative is unique, then this will imply that you cannot have either $[y] = [x]$ or $[y] = -[x]$.  If this is true, then you should expect that
$$[p_1(x) + y q_1(x)] [p_2(x) + y q_2(x)] = [(p_1(x) p_2(x) + x^2 q_1(x) q_2(x)) + y (p_1(x) q_2(x) + q_1(x) p_2(x))].$$
This suggests that you should have that $R$ is isomorphic to a ring with underlying set $\mathbb{Z}[x] \times \mathbb{Z}[x]$, with addition defined by $(p_1, q_1) + (p_2, q_2) = (p_1 + p_2, q_1 + q_2)$ and multiplication defined by
$(p_1, q_1) \cdot (p_2, q_2) = (p_1 p_2 + x^2 q_1 q_2, p_1 q_2 + q_1 p_2)$.  From here, it would be a tedious but straightforward exercise to show that this does define a commutative ring.  Then, in this ring, you clearly have that $(x, 0)^2 = (0, 1)^2 = (x^2, 0)$, but $(x, 0) \ne \pm (0, 1)$.

Comment: This is the *universal* commutative ring with a [nontrivial square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/774914/242). $\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

You have $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}^2$ in the ring of $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb Z/{9\mathbb Z}$. $$3^2=0^2=0$$ but $3\ne\pm 0$